# Generic problem

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Let $54s^2 ± 14s − (9^k − 1) = 0$ for $k$ positive integer will be: 
$s ≡ ±2$ (mod $9$). 
Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we look at this expression modulo $9$, we get
$$ ± 5s ≡ -1$$
Now let's write out $5(n)$ modulo $9$
$$5(1)≡5\mod{9} \\
5(2)≡1\mod{9} \\
5(3)≡6\mod{9} \\
5(4)≡2\mod{9}\\
5(5)≡7\mod{9}\\
5(6)≡3\mod{9}\\
5(7)≡8≡-1\mod{9} \\
5(8)≡4\mod{9}$$
Now let's write out $4(n)$ modulo $9$
$$4(1)≡4\mod{9} \\
4(2)≡8≡-1\mod{9} \\
5(3)≡3\mod{9} \\
5(4)≡7\mod{9}\\
5(5)≡2\mod{9}\\
5(6)≡6\mod{9}\\
5(7)≡1\mod{9} \\
5(8)≡5\mod{9}$$
Thus the only two possibilities are $s ≡ ±2 \mod{9}$

Answer (score 4):

Hint: $\;54\equiv 0 \pmod{9}\,$, $\,14 \equiv 5 \pmod{9}\,$ and $\,9^k \equiv 0 \pmod{9}\,$, so the equation reduces to:

$$
\pm 5s + 1 \equiv 0 \pmod{9} \;\;\iff\;\; 5s \equiv \pm 1 \pmod{9} \;\;\iff\;\; s \equiv 2 \cdot 5 s \equiv \pm 2 \pmod{9}
$$

Comment: thank you, you write this:
$$
5s \equiv \pm 1 \pmod{9} \;\;\iff\;\; s \equiv 2 \cdot 5 s \equiv \pm 2 \pmod{9}
$$
I apologize but I missed the last step, if the last congruence is multiplied by 2 should be module 18. Where am I wrong?

Comment: @CompComp If $a \equiv b \pmod{n}$ and $c \equiv d \pmod{n}$ then both $a+b \equiv c+d \pmod{n}$ and $a\cdot b \equiv c \cdot d \pmod{n}\,$ so $s \equiv s + 9s \equiv 10 s \equiv 2 \cdot 5 s \equiv 2 \cdot (\pm 1) \equiv \pm 2 \pmod{9}\,$.